# Dynamic waits in QTP

Tags: vba, qtp

I am using QTP to test a website in order to ensure all links are working on the pages that the script visits/ I am doing this with a standard Checkpoint that QTP has. The one issue I have is that some pages take a ridiculous amount of time to load due to pictures and other web elements on the page. When a page takes a long time to load it sometimes causes the Checkpoint to fail, because the scripts won't capture all of the links on the page before navigating away (or at least this is my understanding). I got around this by inserting a wait(10) on all pages and that does work like 98% of the time (some pages have terrible lag time). But I was wondering is there someway to write a script such that it will wait until the page loads fully before moving to the checkpoint?

My code looks like

```
Browser(Blah).Navigate URL
wait(10)
Browser(blah).Page(X).Check Checkpoint(K)
Browser(Blah).Navigate URL2
wait(10)
Browser(blah).Page(X).Check Checkpoint(K2)
```

Depending on the script I am running it can check as many as 200 pages and takes several hours to run, so I was hoping I could improve performance if I could get around using a static wait on every page.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ReadyState Enumeration: ([MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb268229%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

```
Enum READYSTATE
    READYSTATE_UNINITIALIZED = 0
    READYSTATE_LOADING = 1
    READYSTATE_LOADED = 2
    READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE = 3
    READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4
End Enum

With Browser(blah)
    .Navigate URL
    '// Wait until page has fully loaded.
    While Not .ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Wend

'// Rest of code here...
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

When you add a checkpoint you can also configure the **Checkpoint Timeout** to ***n*** number of seconds, by default this is set to 10 seconds.

E.g. If you set this to 20 seconds and if your checkpoint passes in 10 seconds then QTP will proceed to the next step immediately. If the Checkpoint does not pass in 20 seconds then it will be marked as fail.

Avoid using the `Wait` statement as much as you can, try to explore other options like `.Sync`, `.Exist` as well.

Comment: Great answer, QTP will wait for the page to have a `readyState` value of `complete` so there's no reason to wait on the `readyState` of the browser. Another function to consider (with `Sync` and `Exist`) is [`WaitProperty`](https://munibala.wordpress.com/2008/05/05/waitproperty-method-of-an-object-6/)